# GBM Rule Generation - Coding Advice

Tags: r, sas, gbm

I use the R package GBM as probably my first choice for predictive modeling. There are so many great things about this algorithm but the one "bad" is that I cant easily use model code to score new data outside of R. I want to write code that can be used in SAS or other system (I will start with SAS (no access to IML)).

Lets say I have the following data set (from GBM manual) and model code:

```
library(gbm)
set.seed(1234)
N <- 1000
X1 <- runif(N)
X2 <- 2*runif(N)
X3 <- ordered(sample(letters[1:4],N,replace=TRUE),levels=letters[4:1])
X4 <- factor(sample(letters[1:6],N,replace=TRUE))
X5 <- factor(sample(letters[1:3],N,replace=TRUE))
X6 <- 3*runif(N)
mu <- c(-1,0,1,2)[as.numeric(X3)]
SNR <- 10 # signal-to-noise ratio
Y <- X1**1.5 + 2 * (X2**.5) + mu
sigma <- sqrt(var(Y)/SNR)
Y <- Y + rnorm(N,0,sigma)
# introduce some missing values
#X1[sample(1:N,size=500)] <- NA
X4[sample(1:N,size=300)] <- NA
X3[sample(1:N,size=30)] <- NA
data <- data.frame(Y=Y,X1=X1,X2=X2,X3=X3,X4=X4,X5=X5,X6=X6)
# fit initial model

gbm1 <- gbm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6, # formula
data=data, # dataset
var.monotone=c(0,0,0,0,0,0), # -1: monotone decrease,
distribution="gaussian", 
n.trees=2, # number of trees
shrinkage=0.005, # shrinkage or learning rate,
# 0.001 to 0.1 usually work
interaction.depth=5, # 1: additive model, 2: two-way interactions, etc.
bag.fraction = 1, # subsampling fraction, 0.5 is probably best
train.fraction = 1, # fraction of data for training,
# first train.fraction*N used for training
n.minobsinnode = 10, # minimum total weight needed in each node
cv.folds = 5, # do 5-fold cross-validation
keep.data=TRUE, # keep a copy of the dataset with the object
verbose=TRUE) # print out progress
```

Now I can see the individual trees using `pretty.gbm.tree` as in

```
pretty.gbm.tree(gbm1,i.tree = 1)[1:7]
```

which yields

```
   SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight
0         2  1.5000000000        1         8          15      983.34315   1000
1         1  1.0309565491        2         6           7      190.62220    501
2         2  0.5000000000        3         4           5       75.85130    277
3        -1 -0.0102671518       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    139
4        -1 -0.0050342273       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    138
5        -1 -0.0076601353       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    277
6        -1 -0.0014569934       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    224
7        -1 -0.0048866747       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    501
8         1  0.6015416372        9        10          14      160.97007    469
9        -1  0.0007403551       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    142
10        2  2.5000000000       11        12          13       85.54573    327
11       -1  0.0046278704       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    168
12       -1  0.0097445692       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    159
13       -1  0.0071158065       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    327
14       -1  0.0051854993       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    469
15       -1  0.0005408284       -1        -1          -1        0.00000     30
```

The manual page 18 shows the following:

[image]

Based on the manual, the first split occurs on the 3rd variable (zero based in this output) which is `gbm1$var.names[3]` "X3". The variable is ordered factor.

```
types<-lapply (lapply(data[,gbm1$var.names],class), function(i) ifelse (strsplit(i[1]," ")[1]=="ordered","ordered",i))

types[3]
```

So, the split is at 1.5 meaning the value 'd and c' `levels[[3]][1:2.5]` (also zero based) splits to left node and the others `levels[[3]][3:4]` go to the right.

Next, the rule continues with a split at `gbm1$var.names[2]` as denoted by SplitVar=1 in the row indexed 1.

Has anyone written anything to move through this data structure (for each tree), constructing rules such as:

"If X3 in ('d','c') and X2<1.0309565491 and X3 in ('d') then scoreTreeOne= -0.0102671518"

which is how I think the first rule from this tree reads.

Or have any advice how to best do this?

Comment: I think IML in SAS could offer a solution. However, I don't really understand R here. Could you interpret more clearly about the pattern?

Comment: Hi Robbie- No access to IML. Looking for a data step. I added the description of the column contents for pretty.gbm.tree.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at [rattle](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rattle/index.html) which implements such a functionality for decision trees (as discussed on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12089/930)). I didn't check myself if this would apply with `gbm` output.

Comment: Have you figured this out?  I've developed metaprogramming from R to SAS for [party::ctree](https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/model-decision-tree-in-r-score-in-sas/) and [nnet](https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/nnet2sas-supports-centering-and-scaling/), and I'd like to have the same for GBM.

Comment: I've written R metaprogramming code to translate a trained GBM model to SAS code, so I can score a data set entirely in SAS (without IML).  It can be done, and the R code is not very long.  However, at this time I am not allowed to share it.

Comment: Well Andrew, good to know its possible, if not very helpful....

Comment: @Andrew , are you able to share your R code or provide some tips? I just did this exercise for a module in sci-kit learn and am not eager to do it all over again in R.

Comment: @Zelazny7: Sorry, I am not allowed to share it at this time, but I will keep trying.  Is your ski-kit implementation public?

Comment: @Andrew: Mostly, I shared it with another SO user who needed a python solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22261053/919872)

Comment: @B_Miner if you still need help with this, I cranked one out this weekend. It's specific to my use case, but it should be fairly easy to edit. Lemme know and we can figure out a discreet way to transfer the files.

Comment: That would be very cool. If you want to send email to b_miner at live dot com !

Comment: @Zelazny7 did you ever get a chance to share this? Do you have a github account?

Answer (score 1):

The [mlmeta](https://github.com/az0/mlmeta) package has a function gbm2sas that exports a GBM model from R to SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very generic answer of how this might be done.

Add some R code to write the output to a file. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html

Then through SAS, access the ability to execute R with: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000303551.htm
(You'll need to know where your R executable is to point the R code you have written above at the executable)

From there you should be able to manipulate the output within SAS to do any scoring you may need.

If it is simply a one time scoring and not a process, omit the SAS execution of R and simply develop SAS code to parse through the R output file.