# mapping scikit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier.tree_.value to predicted class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am using a scikit-learn DecissionTreeClassifier on a 3 class dataset. After I fit the classifier I access all leaf nodes on the tree_ attribute in order to get the amount of instances that end up in a given node for each class.

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5)
clf.fit(X, y)
# lets assume there is a leaf node with id 5
print clf.tree_.value[5]
```

This will print out:

```
>>> array([[  0.,   1.,  68.]])
```

but ... how do I know which position in that array belongs to which class ?
The classifier has a classes_ attribute which is also a list

```
>>> clf.classes_
array(['CLASS_1', 'CLASS_2', 'CLASS_3'], dtype=object)
```

Maybe index 1 on the value array matches the class on index 1 of the classes array and so on?

Comment: Please post an answer separately instead of editing it into the question. Then you can accept your own answer to mark the question as closed.

Comment: @larsmans , is that the common rule ? I once read a post where someone did that and got a comment saying that he should do what I did. Your reputation seems high enough tho. I'll do that and hope no one says to do the contrary :S

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Asked about this on the scikit-learm mailing list and my guess was right. Turns out the index 1 on the value array matches the class on index 1 of the classes array and so on

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not clf.classes_ but clf.tree_.feature that contain the column index of X. And, if X is Pandas DataFrame, X.columns contains the name. You can find more detailed information in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree).

Comment: Hi @jihun, I guess u misunderstood, the value array (clf.tree_.value[5]) does not contain features, it contains the counters for the amount of instances for a given class in that node (in this case node 5), what I need is to map those counters to the corresponding class name.