# Where does scikit-learn hold the decision labels of each leaf node in its tree structure?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, tree-structure

I have trained a random forest model using scikit-learn and now I want to save its tree structures in a text file so I can use it elsewhere.
According to [this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#) a tree object consist of a number of parallel arrays each one hold some information about different nodes of the tree (ex. left child, right child, what feature it examines,...) . However there seems to be no information about the class label corresponding to each leaf node! It's even not mentioned in the examples provided in the link above.

Does anyone know where are the class labels stored in the scikit-learn decision tree structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for [`sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.tree_.value`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
iris = load_iris()

clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

print(clf.classes_)

[0, 1, 2]

print(clf.tree_.value)

[[[ 50.  50.  50.]]

 [[ 50.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.  50.  50.]]

 [[  0.  49.   5.]]

 [[  0.  47.   1.]]

 [[  0.  47.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   1.]]

 [[  0.   2.   4.]]

 [[  0.   0.   3.]]

 [[  0.   2.   1.]]

 [[  0.   2.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   1.]]

 [[  0.   1.  45.]]

 [[  0.   1.   2.]]

 [[  0.   0.   2.]]

 [[  0.   1.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.  43.]]]
```

Each row in `clf.tree_.value` "contains the constant prediction value of each node," (`help(clf.tree_)`) which corresponds index-to-index to `clf.classes_`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26278406/5015569) for (barely) more details.

Comment: Adding to the answer, for each row in this array, you can do `clf.classes_[np.argmax(value)]` to get the predicted class label.

Comment: @not_a_robot Thanks. you explained it perfectly. However I still can't find where clf.tree_.value is mentioned in the documentation. I guess I don't need it anymore since your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just another quick question. Looks like clf.classes_ gives me labels of [0,...,n-1], regardless of what labels I use. Am I right? I was expecting [1,...,n] In my case.

Comment: I believe the labels are zero-indexed, which is why it's [0, *n*-1].