# get the actual decision tree in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tree, classification, decision-tree

I'm using pandas command `tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` to build a (binary) classification tree. Something along the lines of:

```
dcrG = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',splitter='best',options_go_here)
dcrG.fit(train[features], train['G'])
```

Now that I have succesfully built my decision tree, I would like pandas to print me out the actual decision tree, so something along the lines of

```
if (var1>0.4) 
  if (var4>3.24)
    if (var2<0.5)
      return 1
    else
      return 0
  else
    return 1
else
  if (var3>3.5)
    if (var2<0.1)
      return 0
    else
      return 1
  else
    if (var2>0.4)
      return 1
    else
      return 0
```

so that I can export the resulting algorithm to other programming languages. How can I do this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree

Comment: Aha, been using the wrong keywords in my search apparently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a great solution to this here: https://gist.github.com/cstrelioff/8fefa9a43e82d96e9f0c