# How to extract decision rules (features splits) from xgboost model in python3?

Tags: python, xgboost

I need to extract the decision rules from my fitted xgboost model in python. I use 0.6a2 version of xgboost library and my python version is 3.5.2.

My ultimate goal is to use those splits to bin variables ( according to the splits).

I did not come across any property of the model for this version which can give me splits.

`plot_tree` is giving me something similar. However it is visualization of the tree.

I need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/39772170/4559070 for xgboost model

Answer (score 20):

It is possible, but not easy. I would recommend you to use `GradientBoostingClassifier` from `scikit-learn`, which is similar to `xgboost`, but has native access to the built trees.

With `xgboost`, however, it is possible to get a textual representation of the model and then parse it:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
# build a very simple model
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
model = XGBClassifier(max_depth=2, n_estimators=2)
model.fit(X, y);
# dump it to a text file
model.get_booster().dump_model('xgb_model.txt', with_stats=True)
# read the contents of the file
with open('xgb_model.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt_model = f.read()
print(txt_model)
```

It will print you a textual description of 6 trees (2 estimators, each consists of 3 trees, one per class), which starts like this:

```
booster[0]:
0:[f2<2.45] yes=1,no=2,missing=1,gain=72.2968,cover=66.6667
    1:leaf=0.143541,cover=22.2222
    2:leaf=-0.0733496,cover=44.4444
booster[1]:
0:[f2<2.45] yes=1,no=2,missing=1,gain=18.0742,cover=66.6667
    1:leaf=-0.0717703,cover=22.2222
    2:[f3<1.75] yes=3,no=4,missing=3,gain=41.9078,cover=44.4444
        3:leaf=0.124,cover=24
        4:leaf=-0.0668394,cover=20.4444
...
```

Now you can, for example, extract all splits from this description:

```
import re
# trying to extract all patterns like "[f2<2.45]"
splits = re.findall('\[f([0-9]+)<([0-9]+.[0-9]+)\]', txt_model)
splits
```

It will print you the list of tuples (feature_id, split_value), like

```
[('2', '2.45'),
 ('2', '2.45'),
 ('3', '1.75'),
 ('3', '1.65'),
 ('2', '4.95'),
 ('2', '2.45'),
 ('2', '2.45'),
 ('3', '1.75'),
 ('3', '1.65'),
 ('2', '4.95')]
```

You can further process this list as you wish.

Comment: Might need to use `'\[f([0-9]+)<([0-9]+.[0-9-e]+)\]'` for the regex to pick up scientific notation. I needed to extract the leaf values and this modification was required to grab them all.

Comment: how can I know what each feature id actually represents ? like what is `f2` actually for ?

Comment: @JacquelineP., the ids of the features are just the ordinal numbers of the corresponding columns in the X matrix.

Comment: You could also use `model.get_booster().get_dump()` instead of writing to file.

Comment: And there is also `model.get_booster().trees_to_dataframe()`, which will give something closer to the desired outcome.

Answer (score 8):

You can find the decision rules as a dataframe through the function `model._Booster.trees_to_dataframe()`.
The `Yes` column contains the `ID` of the yes-branch, and the `No` column of the no-branch. This way you can reconstruct the tree, since for each row of the dataframe, the node `ID` has directed edges to `Yes` and `No`. You can do that with networkx like so:

```
import networkx as nx

df = model._Booster.trees_to_dataframe()

# Create graph
G = nx.Graph()
# Add all the nodes
G.add_nodes_from(df.ID.tolist())
# Add the edges. This should be simpler in Pandas, but there seems to be a bug with df.apply(tuple, axis=1) at the moment.
yes_pairs = df[['ID', 'Yes']].dropna()
no_pairs = df[['ID', 'No']].dropna()
yes_edges = [tuple([i[0], i[1]]) for i in yes_pairs.values]
no_edges = [tuple([i[0], i[1]]) for i in no_pairs.values]
G.add_edges_from(yes_edges + no_edges)
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code fragment which prints all the rules extracted from the booster trees from xgboost model.

The below code is based on the missing values substitution with 999999

```
import networkx as nx

df = model._Booster.trees_to_dataframe()

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(df.ID.tolist())

yes_edges = df[['ID', 'Yes', 'Feature', 'Split']].dropna()
yes_edges['label'] = yes_edges.apply(lambda x: "({feature} > {value:.2f} or {feature} = 999999)".format(feature=x['Feature'], value=x['Split']), axis=1)

no_edges = df[['ID', 'No', 'Feature', 'Split']].dropna()
no_edges['label'] = no_edges.apply(lambda x: "({feature} < {value:.2f})".format(feature=x['Feature'], value=x['Split']), axis=1)

for v in yes_edges.values:
    G.add_edge(v[0],v[1], feature=v[2], expr=v[4])
    
for v in no_edges.values:
    G.add_edge(v[0],v[1], feature=v[2], expr=v[4])

leaf_node_values = {i[0]:i[1] for i in df[df.Feature=='Leaf'][['ID','Gain']].values}    
    
roots = []
leaves = []
for node in G.nodes :
    if G.in_degree(node) == 0 : # it's a root
        roots.append(node)
    elif G.out_degree(node) == 0 : # it's a leaf
        leaves.append(node)
        
paths = []
for root in roots :
    for leaf in leaves :
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaf) :
            paths.append(path)
    
pred_conditions = []
for path in paths:
    parts = []
    for i in range(len(path)-1):
        parts.append(G[path[i]][path[i+1]]['expr'])
    pred_conditions.append("if " + " and ".join(parts) + " then {value:.4f}".format(value=leaf_node_values.get(path[-1])))
```

The above code prints every rule in the format as below:

```
if x>y and a>b and c<d then e
```

Answer (score -15):

You need to know the name of your tree, and after that, you can insert it into your code.