# Plot Tree within XGBoost without Graphviz

Tags: python, xgboost

I am currently trying to understand the XGBoostClassifier model I have generated. Unfortunately due to company restrictions I am unable to install GraphViz into the environment. Are there any alternatives to the xgboost.plot() that I can try, which do not require Graphviz.

Comment: Can you install anything in your environment? If you can install pure python packages, you could try this answer that extracts the decision tree data and reconstructs it as a networkx graph (which does not rely on graphviz): https://stackoverflow.com/a/65048552/9357244

Comment: If XGBoost (?) can produce a text file as output to be used by Graphviz as input, you can then use one of the Web-based Graphviz sites - no Graphviz install needed.