# Get split points from DecisionTreeClassifier for single numeric variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to get splits from decision tree created based on a single variable. Is the following the correct and safe way how to get the splits?

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
y = np.array([1,0,0,1,1,0,1])
x = x.reshape(7, -1)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(x, y)

# My splits
np.sort(clf.tree_.threshold[clf.tree_.feature == 0])
```

I see only `0` and `-2` in `clf.tree_.fature` and my understanding is that `-2` represents `TREE_UNDEFINED` (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx)) while the other points will be leafs with some defined threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct to obtain the splits, but you have the order reveresed. 
`-2` represents the leaf nodes as you can see from [this code section](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bb5110b8e0b70d98eae2f7f8b6d4deaa5d2de038/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L749) while others are internal node. There is however a problem with this method that you cannot simply resconstruct the order or how these splits are placed in the final structure of the tree.

Take a look at [this official example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py), which is a more thorough way to get the exact split and node structure.

**References**

- [How to extract the decision rules from scikit-learn decision-tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree)