# How to extract sklearn decision tree rules to pandas boolean conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

There are so many posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree) about how to extract sklearn decision tree rules but I could not find any about using pandas.

Take [this data and model](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/decision-tree-classification-python) for example, as below

```
# Create Decision Tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth=3)

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

The result:

[image]

Expected:

There're 8 rules about this example.

From left to right,notice that dataframe is `df`

```
r1 = (df['glucose']<=127.5) & (df['bmi']<=26.45) & (df['bmi']<=9.1)
……
r8 =  (df['glucose']>127.5) & (df['bmi']>28.15) & (df['glucose']>158.5)
```

I'm not a master of extracting sklearn decision tree rules. Getting the pandas boolean conditions will help me calculate samples and other metrics for each rule. So I want to extract each rule to a pandas boolean condition.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all let's use the scikit [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html) on decision tree structure to get information about the tree that was constructed :

```
n_nodes = clf.tree_.node_count
children_left = clf.tree_.children_left
children_right = clf.tree_.children_right
feature = clf.tree_.feature
threshold = clf.tree_.threshold
```

We then define two recursive functions. The first one will find the path from the tree's root to create a specific node (all the leaves in our case). The second one will write the specific rules used to create a node using its creation path :

```
def find_path(node_numb, path, x):
        path.append(node_numb)
        if node_numb == x:
            return True
        left = False
        right = False
        if (children_left[node_numb] !=-1):
            left = find_path(children_left[node_numb], path, x)
        if (children_right[node_numb] !=-1):
            right = find_path(children_right[node_numb], path, x)
        if left or right :
            return True
        path.remove(node_numb)
        return False


def get_rule(path, column_names):
    mask = ''
    for index, node in enumerate(path):
        #We check if we are not in the leaf
        if index!=len(path)-1:
            # Do we go under or over the threshold ?
            if (children_left[node] == path[index+1]):
                mask += "(df['{}']<= {}) \t ".format(column_names[feature[node]], threshold[node])
            else:
                mask += "(df['{}']> {}) \t ".format(column_names[feature[node]], threshold[node])
    # We insert the & at the right places
    mask = mask.replace("\t", "&", mask.count("\t") - 1)
    mask = mask.replace("\t", "")
    return mask
```

Finally, we use those two functions to first store the creation path of each leaf. And then to store the rules used to create each leaf :

```
# Leaves
leave_id = clf.apply(X_test)

paths ={}
for leaf in np.unique(leave_id):
    path_leaf = []
    find_path(0, path_leaf, leaf)
    paths[leaf] = np.unique(np.sort(path_leaf))

rules = {}
for key in paths:
    rules[key] = get_rule(paths[key], pima.columns)
```

---

With the data you gave the output is :

```
rules =
{3: "(df['insulin']<= 127.5) & (df['bp']<= 26.450000762939453) & (df['bp']<= 9.100000381469727)  ",
 4: "(df['insulin']<= 127.5) & (df['bp']<= 26.450000762939453) & (df['bp']> 9.100000381469727)  ",
 6: "(df['insulin']<= 127.5) & (df['bp']> 26.450000762939453) & (df['skin']<= 27.5)  ",
 7: "(df['insulin']<= 127.5) & (df['bp']> 26.450000762939453) & (df['skin']> 27.5)  ",
 10: "(df['insulin']> 127.5) & (df['bp']<= 28.149999618530273) & (df['insulin']<= 145.5)  ",
 11: "(df['insulin']> 127.5) & (df['bp']<= 28.149999618530273) & (df['insulin']> 145.5)  ",
 13: "(df['insulin']> 127.5) & (df['bp']> 28.149999618530273) & (df['insulin']<= 158.5)  ",
 14: "(df['insulin']> 127.5) & (df['bp']> 28.149999618530273) & (df['insulin']> 158.5)  "}
```

Since the rules are strings, you can't directly call them using `df[rules[3]]`, you have to use the eval function like so `df[eval(rules[3])]`

Comment: excellent, but the rules what I want is using column names. Would you mind answering it?

Comment: anthor problem is when using dataframe select based on boolean conditions like df[rules[4]],it get error. how to solve it

Comment: @Jack I changed the recursive function `get_rule` to display the columns. And I pointed out why you get the error at the end of the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Now you can use export_text.

```
from sklearn.tree import export_text

r = export_text(loan_tree, feature_names=(list(X_train.columns)))
print(r)
```

A complete example from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_text.html)

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_text
iris = load_iris()
X = iris['data']
y = iris['target']
decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=2)
decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(X, y)
r = export_text(decision_tree, feature_names=iris['feature_names'])
print(r)
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a further solution to this problem (a second part to the one posted by vlemaistre) which allows the user to run through any node and subset the data based on the pandas boolean condition.

```
node_id = 3

def datatree_path_summarystats(node_id):
    for k, v in paths.items():
        if node_id in v:
            d = k,v

    ruleskey = d[0]
    numberofsteps = sum(map(lambda x : x<node_id, d[1]))

    for k, v in rules.items():
        if k == ruleskey:
            b = k,v

    stringsubset = b[1]

    datasubset = "&".join(stringsubset.split('&')[:numberofsteps])
    return datasubset

datasubset = datatree_path_summarystats(node_id)

df[eval(datasubset)]
```

This function runs through the paths that contain the node id you are looking for. It will then split the rule based on that number of nodes creating the logic to subset the dataframe based on that one specific node.